# Rounding jQuery .height() Down

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, height, rounding

I'm using a collage on a recent project which has a button with text in the center. I'm using jQuery to assign the height of the button equal to the surrounding divs, that contain the  images, so that they stack nicely in Bootstrap.

The issue I am having is that the .height() function returns the height rounded up or down depending on the size of the surround divs, which can through off the layout - IE. if it's rounding to 256px and the other divs are 255.65px, it'll push the content below it down.

I was wondering if there was an easy way to force the .height() function to round the number returned down - no matter what.

Here's my code: (I was having some issues with the collage on Safari and I had to detect what browser the viewer was using and adjust accordingly.)

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            $(window).on('load resize', function () {
            // Check for Safari - if Safari delete div height of button by 6px. Fixed resize stacking bug on Safari browsers
            if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') && !navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome')) {

                var divheight = $(".image").height();

                /* Remove 6px on button - to account for border on Safari */
                $(".visitor-button").height(divheight-6);

                } else {

                var divheight = $(".image").height();
                $(".visitor-button").height(divheight);

                }
            });

            </script>
```

EDIT =============================================================

I added the Math.floor function but it doesn't seem to be working. After checking on Chrome it looks like when the images at 177.65px tall it makes the div 178px tall. Here's the new code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(window).on('load resize', function () {
            // Check for Safari - if Safari delete div height of button by 6px. Fixed resize stacking bug on Safari browsers
            if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') && !navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome')) {

                var divheight = $(".image").height();
                /* Remove 6px on button - to account for border on Safari */
                $(".visitor-button").height(divheight-6);
            } else {
                var divheight = $(".image").height();
                var newheight = Math.floor(divheight);
                $(".visitor-button").height(newheight);
            }
            });

            </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript's `Math.floor()` function to round the `divheight` to previous integer value and then use it in `height()` function.

Comment: It still doesn't seem to work, I edited my question to show new code. Thanks for the help!